# Return filtered array once compared to value of object property in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to dynamically update a table in my AngularJS app, based on what the user inputs. I have an `updateCategory` function that is invoked by `ng-change` in the view and should return a new array to `vm.portfolioData` in the controller.

The `el.serviceList` provides a property, `serviceStatus`, which provides a string value, which then needs to be checked if it is included in a object property in a second array, `actionStatus`:

```
function updateCategory(obj, position) {
  vm.portfolioData = patents;
  vm.portfolioData = vm.portfolioData.filter(function(el){
     return el.serviceList.filter(function(item){
        //item.serviceStatus: "Epct available"
        //NEED TO RETURN EL IF STATUS IS CONTAINED IN SECOND ARRAY
     }
  })
}
```

***Second array***

```
actionStatus: [
   {name: 'Epct available'},
   {name: 'Epct saved'}, 
   {name: 'Form 1200 saved'}, 
   {name: 'Epct rejected'}, 
   {name: 'Show price'}, 
   {name: 'Open for Renewal'}, 
   {name: 'Form 1200 generating'}
 ]
```

***Question***

How do I return the new filtered array once I have checked if the `serviceStatus` value is contained in any of the objects property `name` in the second array?

Comment: Hi @Patrick you want to return whole array or just one element which contains ?

Comment: Whole array containing items that had their `serviceStatus` value match one of the statuses from `actionStatus`. Tbh I think @Saka7 method should work, just trying to solve issue of item that returned false being returned to array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const serviceList = [
    {serviceStatus: 'Epct available'},
    {serviceStatus: 'Epct not available'},
];

const actionStatus = [
    {name: 'Epct available'},
    {name: 'Epct saved'},
    {name: 'Form 1200 saved'},
    {name: 'Epct rejected'},
    {name: 'Show price'},
    {name: 'Open for Renewal'},
    {name: 'Form 1200 generating'}
];

const actionStatusStrings = actionStatus.map(item => item.name);

const filteredArray = serviceList.filter(item => {
    return actionStatusStrings.includes(item.serviceStatus);
});
```

Regarding your case:

```
function updateCategory(obj, position) {
  vm.portfolioData = patents;

  const actionStatusStrings = actionStatus.map(item => item.name);

  vm.portfolioData = vm.portfolioData.filter(el => {
    return el.serviceList.find(item => {
        return actionStatusStrings.includes(item.serviceStatus);
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Only issue is that it is returning items even if their `serviceStatus` didn't match a status from `actionStatus` array? In the console it returns value false but is still included in array?

Comment: It shouldn't, the example above will return only one item `[{serviceStatus: 'Epct available'}]`. The problem is not in `filter`.

Comment: `serviceList` in my script is an array nested in each item in `vm.portfolioData`. Would this cause this issue?

Comment: What is the outer `filter` for?  Maybe you should use `map` instead. I just don't know what is the business logic behind that.

`vm.portfolioData.map(i => Object.assing(i, {serviceList: /* ... */ }))`

Comment: The outer filter was used to select the nested `serviceList` array. Guessing that was a mistake

Comment: If you need to update an array of each `portfolioData`'s `serviceList` property you can use the example I've provided above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182081/discussion-between-patrick-mcdermott-and-saka7).